# Excel 2010: DATE/HOUR Formating

Tags: excel

Hello everyone i have this problem in excel 2010. It's a problem of cell format. The cell has **DATE/HOU**R as title that means this is the info in the cell: **02/09/14 12:12:11** and i want to format it to show only hours.Can this happen? I have tried the usual cell formating hours:min but it does take effect to the rest 5.000 cells

What i have to do is this enter to a cell and press enter.
It is impossible to continue like this for the rest 5.000 lines.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

I had flag to close your question because it is off-topic for StackOverflow, which is a site for programming-related questions, but:

1. Left-click the column header for the column you want to change.  This will select every single cell for that column only.
2. Next **Right-click** the column header
3. Choose "Format Cells" from the menu that appears
4. In the Number tab, underneath Category, choose "Custom"
5. In the edit control underneath "Type", enter "hh"

In the future, please keep in mind that
Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on SuperUser (http://superuser.com).